# Play mp4 fullscreen automatically when click play

Tags: jquery, html, video

I have a webpage with a video link, when the user click on the link, the user will be directed to the mp4 file etc example.com/myvideo.mp4. Just wondering if is it possible when user click play, the video will automatically go full screen? I did some research, it seems like we need a button to trigger it to play fullscreen.

Comment: Create a fiddle please.

Comment: Open the video the link in the browser like this http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4. The browser's inbuilt player will play this based on your video resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information regarding FULLSCREEN API here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API